# Date in sql 2005,asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

If i didn't place any date in the textbox ,system is capturing 1/1/1900 by default insted of Null.How can i get rid of this.

cmd.CommandText = "Update FormMaster                                       set              BriefingDate ='" + TextBox7.Text + "'

where FormID =" & Val(AutoID.Text)

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recomend that you specifically check the value of TextBox7 before and assign to a var, so if the date is correct assign the value "'" + TextBox7.Text + "'" else just assign NULL.

this would lead to statement being UPDATE TABLE SET DATE = NULL if required OR UPDATE TABLE SET DATE = 'DATE' otherwise

Answer (score 2):

1) Please use the cmd.Parameters collection to set SQL parameter values.

2) Write a function ToDBNullableDate(string) which converts a string into a DateTime and an empty string to DBNull

```
object ToDBNullableDate(string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        return DBNull.Value
    return Convert.ToDateTime(s);
}
```